# Retrieve only the HTML structure (All DOM elements) from HTML file

Tags: c#, html

I want to retrieve only the structure of HTML document using C# as there is a requirement to create a template from the document and store in a database,which can be used in the future to compare if such a document was earlier received and process further For eg if have the below simple HTML:

```
<HTML>
   <BODY>
      <DIV name="Span1">Simple HTML Form</DIV>
      <FORM>  
         <SPAN name="TextLabel">EID: 12345</SPAN>  
         <SPAN name="TextLabel1">Date:'2019-07-10'</SPAN>    
      </FORM>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Name </td>
            <td> Occupation</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> XYZ </td>
            <td> SSE </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want the following output:

```
<HTML>
   <BODY>
      <DIV></DIV>
      <FORM>  
         <SPAN></SPAN>  
         <SPAN></SPAN>    
      </FORM>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Is code indentation needed or is it fine to remove all text nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Using **HtmlAgilityPack** might be an option. You can start from this example and develop...

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            string html = @"<HTML>
   <BODY>
      <DIV name=""Span1"">Simple HTML Form</DIV>
      <FORM>  
         <SPAN name=""TextLabel"">EID: 12345</SPAN>  
         <SPAN name=""TextLabel1"">Date:'2019-07-10'</SPAN>    
      </FORM>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Name </td>
            <td> Occupation</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> XYZ </td>
            <td> SSE </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </BODY>
</HTML>";

doc.LoadHtml(html);

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use Regex :

```
string html = @"<HTML>
   <BODY>
      <DIV name=""Span1"">Simple HTML Form</DIV>
      <FORM>  
         <SPAN name=""TextLabel"">EID: 12345</SPAN>  
         <SPAN name=""TextLabel1"">Date:'2019-07-10'</SPAN>    
      </FORM>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Name </td>
            <td> Occupation</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> XYZ </td>
            <td> SSE </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </BODY>
</HTML>";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"<.+?>");
MatchCollection match = regex.Matches(html);

foreach(var item in match)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```